# Could Bran warg into a messenger raven, fly to Kings Landing, and poke Joffrey in the eye?

Tags: game-of-thrones

I am watching Game of Thrones on my own time schedule cause I don't have HBO. I just finished Season #3. However, I want to know one spoiler:

Once Bran has mastered warging, could he warg into a messenger raven, fly to Kings Landing, and then try to poke Joffrey in the eye? If he can't, please explain exactly why he cannot?

I get the feeling that warging has ended my love affair with Game of Thrones.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, because

> Joffrey is dead long before Bran masters his Warg abilities.

Well, you *did* ask for a spoiler.

Aside from that, there are warg characters in the books

> like Varamyr Sixskins

who abuse their warg companions to intimidate others, but they're rare.  I mean, controlling an animal doesn't give you superpowers.  For the most part, animals are *below* humans in the food chain.  And humans have always been reasonably good at ganging up on bullies and pulling them down in the end - just ask Aerys Targaryen, the Second of His Name.

Aside from that, if manageable dragons are a deal breaker for you, you should have gotten leary of the series two seasons ago.

Comment: whatever. Bran technically could, but he just doesn't want to, right? And, I get a sick feeling Bran will warg into a dragon (which is beyond stupid). Except for Bran and Shae, those actors were fricking amazing. Definitely worth 30 hours of my time.

Comment: thanks. I get it now. Fire breathing dragons, wights, then... warging a dragon by a seemingly crippled boy from Winterfell. Well, I'm praying to the old and new gods that someone hurrys-up and hangs Shae. I'll watch that episode!!!